# What is the HashSet<T> in Sample Code?

Tags: entity-framework, generics, hashset

In this Virtual property that is used in an EF class why is it returning `HashSet<T>`? What is that class?

```
  public virtual ICollection<TownShip> TownShips
    {
        get
        {
            return this.TownShips ?? (this.TownShips = new HashSet<TownShip>());
        }

        set
        {
            this.TownShips = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HashSet<T>` is a generic class that implements the `ICollection<T>` interface. From the documentation:

> The HashSet class provides high-performance set operations. A set
>   is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose
>   elements are in no particular order.

In the code, if the property Townships is null, than an empty collection (HashSet) is returned.

[HashSet of T's Documentation Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)

Comment: in this code ,I know about approach HashSet Class. I do not know why in this code use HashSet but I wanna Know that in this property has any performance with HashSet<T> or without using HashSet<T>?

Comment: @user1150581 You want to know why HashSet<T> is used in this property? Is the code auto-generated from something like a T4 template?

Comment: Yes I want Know Why Use HashSet<T> in this Code?

Comment: Is the code autogenerated, did you write it, did a co-worker write it? It does not necessarily have to be a HashSet (I have used generic collections in the past, and T4 templates I've looked at have used other collections also).